# Difference between the working of $lte:10 and $not:{$gt:10} on an array in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, comparison-operators

We can see that when using "grades.score":{$lte:10} , score with value greater than 10 also appear in the grades array. But when "grades.score":{$not:{$gt:10}} is used they are filtered out. 
Though the meaning of both appear as same.

Here is the sample of collection i.e. "restaurants":

```
{
  "address": {
     "building": "1007",
     "coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
     "street": "Morris Park Ave",
     "zipcode": "10462"
  },
  "borough": "Bronx",
  "cuisine": "Bakery",
  "grades": [
     { "grade": "A", "score": 2 },
     { "grade": "A", "score": 6 },
     { "grade": "A", "score": 10 },
     { "grade": "A", "score": 9 },
     { "grade": "B", "score": 14 }
  ],
  "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
  "restaurant_id": "30075445"
}
```

Here is 1st query:

`db.restaurants.find({"grades.score":{$lte:10}},{"grades.score":1,name:1,restau
rant_id:1,borough:1,cuisine:1,_id:0}).pretty()`

Result:

```
{
    "borough" : "Queens",
    "cuisine" : "Ice Cream, Gelato, Yogurt, Ices",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "score" : 9
            },
            {
                    "score" : 10
            },
            {
                    "score" : 13
            }
    ],
    "name" : "Carvel Ice Cream",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361322"
}
{
    "borough" : "Brooklyn",
    "cuisine" : "Delicatessen",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "score" : 4
            },
            {
                    "score" : 3
            },
            {
                    "score" : 10
            }
    ],
    "name" : "Nordic Delicacies",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361390"
}
{
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "American ",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "score" : 12
            },
            {
                    "score" : 16
            },
            {
                    "score" : 9
            },
            {
                    "score" : 13
            },
            {
                    "score" : 11
            }
    ],
    "name" : "Glorious Food",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361521"
}
{
    "borough" : "Brooklyn",
    "cuisine" : "American ",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "score" : 11
            },
            {
                    "score" : 2
            },
            {
                    "score" : 13
            },
            {
                    "score" : 11
            }
    ],
    "name" : "The Movable Feast",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361606"
}
{
    "borough" : "Queens",
    "cuisine" : "Delicatessen",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "score" : 12
            },
            {
                    "score" : 9
            },
            {
                    "score" : 7
            },
            {
                    "score" : 10
            }
    ],
    "name" : "Sal'S Deli",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361618"
}
```

Here is 2nd query:

`db.restaurants.find({"grades.score":{$not:{$gt:10}}},       {"grades.score":1,name:1,restaurant_id:1,borough:1,cuisine:1,_id:0}).pretty()`

Result:

```
{
    "borough" : "Bronx",
    "cuisine" : "American ",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "score" : 5
            },
            {
                    "score" : 3
            },
            {
                    "score" : 4
            },
            {
                    "score" : 9
            }
    ],
    "name" : "African Market (Baboon Cafe)",
    "restaurant_id" : "40368026"
}
{
    "borough" : "Staten Island",
    "cuisine" : "Italian",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "score" : 10
            },
            {
                    "score" : 3
            },
            {
                    "score" : 6
            },
            {
                    "score" : 10
            }
    ],
    "name" : "Roadhouse Restaurant",
    "restaurant_id" : "40368034"
}
{
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "French",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "score" : 9
            },
            {
                    "score" : 2
            },
            {
                    "score" : 8
            }
    ],
    "name" : "Pergola Des Artistes",
    "restaurant_id" : "40369139"
}
{
    "borough" : "Brooklyn",
    "cuisine" : "Hamburgers",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "score" : 10
            },
            {
                    "score" : 7
            },
            {
                    "score" : 5
            },
            {
                    "score" : 10
            }
    ],
    "name" : "Mcdonald'S",
    "restaurant_id" : "40369535"
}
{
    "borough" : "Brooklyn",
    "cuisine" : "American ",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "score" : 10
            },
            {
                    "score" : 8
            }
    ],
    "name" : "The River Cafe",
    "restaurant_id" : "40369608"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your queries actually filter items out of the `grades` array.

> **[Query a Field that Contains an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-a-field-that-contains-an-array)**
>
> If a field contains an array and your query has multiple conditional operators, the field as a whole **will match if either a single array element meets the conditions** or a combination of array elements meet the conditions.

Your 1st query,

```
db.restaurants.find({"grades.score":{$lte:10}},{"grades.score":1,name:1,restaurant_id:1,borough:1, cuisine:1,_id:0}).pretty()
```

returns documents that contain **at least one** item in the `grades` array that has a `score` value less than or equal to 10.

Your 2nd query,

```
db.restaurants.find({"grades.score":{$not:{$gt:10}}},{"grades.score":1,name:1,restaurant_id:1,borough:1,cuisine:1,_id:0}).pretty()
```

returns documents that don't have any item in the `grades` array that has a `score` value greater than 10.

What I assume you intended to do, is described in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12241930/3099132).

Comment: Thans to answer but what i assume that both query should give exactly equal result. So how are they giving different results ?

Comment: If all documents had a single item in the `grades` array, then you would get the same results. `.find({"grades.score": ... })` returns all items of the array if at least a single element in that array matches the condition.